# Reading environment variables on build.gradle from GitLab

Tags: android, gradle, gitlab, build.gradle

I'm using GitLab for the CI on my Android apps and I have defined a set of secrets to generate the release builds from the main branch.

I read the secrets using these lines on my `build.gradle` file

```
Properties keyProps = new Properties()
keyProps.setProperty("store", System.getenv("store").toString())
```

this worked fine until I updated my compile and target SDK versions to 31, now this command is not working and returns `null` for all the properties.

How can I retrieve the secrets from GitLab in my `build.gradle` files? Thanks!